# Latest Ubuntu upgrade has crashed my laptop

Tags: 18.10

When upgrading to the latest Ubuntu desktop software my laptop hangs when trying to restart. It went through all the screens and got to “restart”, now stuck on purple coloured screen when trying to start

Comment: I think you mean 19.10 not 18.10 right?

Comment: @Dougal Henderson Please see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze#Problem:__Freeze_began_after_a_system_update

Comment: 18.10 is no longer supported.  What version are you actually having issues with?

Comment: Yes sorry 19.10